# Cannot create files/folders in new partition

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have created one partition from 500gb HDD and mounted it permanently. Now the problem is I cannot create anything in that partition. But I can able to create the files and folders with sudo access. I have mounted the partition in /media/user.

I have changed the 755 permission for the user dir. Please suggest to fix this. Thanks.

Comment: by default, only root will have permission to this partition. If you really want to create data there give 1777 permission to partition like we have for /tmp folder. But better to use sudo only

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the user and group ownership of the directory (and its contents) using `ls -l`. If you don't own it, that would explain the behaviour you described. That can be fixed with this:

```
sudo chown -R username:group directory
```

This can happen with mounted filesystems that you use `sudo` to mount. So changing your mount command to this might help in future:

```
mount device mount-point -o uid=<username> -o gid=<group>
```

In both these examples, the `group` will almost certainly be your username, unless you have a special group so that multiple users can interact with the mounted drive. If that's the case, then you will need `775` or `774` permissions to allow group members to write, and you'll also need to set `chmod g+s` (or `chmod 1774` will do the same) to ensure all group members can access newly created files in future. (This is a very common configuration for shared media folders.) The `uid` and `gid` options will work in your `/etc/fstab/ file as well, since you say the partition is mounted permanently, this is most likely where you've done it.

Incidentally, setting `1777` permissions is not considered a great idea, as it grants much greater permission than required, and allows the folder to be globally written to and executed from. If something is misconfigured and you end up with a malicious file written there, it can be executed by any user or process. Unless you are very confident of your security and the implications of `1777` permissions, I'd avoid them.